# Page's height is too long on mobile. How to reduce the length

Tags: html, css

I am working on getting my website to be fully responsive and am experiencing some trouble with getting the formatting for mobile to look correct. The page's height is too long on mobile and content is not large enough for the user to see clearly; I've attached a photo of what this looks like.

Here is the page's CSS code:

```
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 55%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 23%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 15px;
}

.home-header {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    color: #ebcabc;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1;
}

.home-buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-left: 10%;
    text-align: left
}

.button {
    height: 70%;
}

.about-container {
    width: 75%;
}

.main-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 13.5%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}

.tiktok {
    width: 15%;
    height: 70%;
    padding-left: 15%;
}
.mail {
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
.calendly {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

CSS code for mobile

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .home-header {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .parent-container {
        border-width: 10px;
    }
    .main-text {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .home-buttons {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-left: 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .whatever
     {
        width: 75%;
        height: 70%;
    }
    .button-txt {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
    button {
        bottom: 20%;
    }
    .tiktok {
        width: 15%;
        height: 70%;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    .mail {
        width: 25%;
        height: 70%;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    .calendly {
        margin-left: 60px;
    }
   }
```

How can I reduce the height of the page for mobile?

[image: web page image]

Comment: Just checking: you've got your `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` line in, right?

Comment: `margin-left: 23%` sounds a bit much for a mobile screen? You don't override that in your mobile css.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question @NicolasGoosen asked, Make sure you have that meta tag he gave you in the <head> section of your html. It keeps mobile devices from doing weird stuff to the page size.

Comment: @NicolasGoosen thanks! I actually didn't include that tag, but I went ahead and added it. Everything is looking good now